# Magento2: How to remove PERIOD option from the report?

Tags: magento2, reports

I am creating a custom report.

I don't need **Period** and **Empty Rows** Option from the report.

How can I remove it?

[image: io]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can able to find the `Period` and `Empty Rows` from the below core block file. You can override that core file to custom module and remove that field.

> File path:
>   magento/vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Adminhtml/Filter/Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'period_type',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'period_type',
                'options' => ['day' => __('Day'), 'month' => __('Month'), 'year' => __('Year')],
                'label' => __('Period'),
                'title' => __('Period')
            ]
        );

$fieldset->addField(
    'show_empty_rows',
    'select',
    [
        'name' => 'show_empty_rows',
        'options' => ['1' => __('Yes'), '0' => __('No')],
        'label' => __('Empty Rows'),
        'title' => __('Empty Rows')
    ]
);
```

Hope it help.

Comment: I got the same solution, But Thanks for the Answer. May It helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the column using layout xml. 
File path : app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/salereport_report_sales_customsalereport.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="reports_sales"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Customsalereport" template="Magento_Reports::report/grid/container.phtml" name="sales.report.grid.container">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Filter\Form" name="grid.filter.form">
                    <action method="setFieldVisibility">
                        <argument name="field" xsi:type="string">period_type</argument>
                        <argument name="visibility" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="setFieldVisibility">
                        <argument name="field" xsi:type="string">show_empty_rows</argument>
                        <argument name="visibility" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```